# How to set dynamic variables into SQL query in Azure HttpTrigger function with cosmosdb input

Tags: sql, azure, url, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I want to pass Url parameters into SQL query with Azure Http Trigger Function to get data

Here is my simple SQL query in cosmosdb input bindings:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.id in ({param1}, {param2})
```

As you can see this is hardcoded , I want it to be dynamic .

Is there any way to query URL parameters dynamically with SQL ?

Comment: You mean you want to parameterized `SqlQuery` property  in cosmos db bindings:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb?tabs=csharp#input---configuration? Or you just want to implement parameterized sql inside function method with code?

Comment: @JayGong Yes , in cosmos db bindings .

Comment: if you are using stored procedure  SELECT * FROM c where c.id in  (" + idParamString + ") try this.